# Jackson deserialization behaviour for a getter without property

Tags: java, jackson

While using jackson to deserialize and serialize a java DTO came across a weird behaviour.
Consider this sample java dto,

```
public class TempClz {

    private List<String> field1;

    public List<String> getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(List<String> field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public List<String> getNotAtAll() {
        return field1;
    }
}
```

Now on creating a object of this class with field1 set to some value and on serializing this via a standard jackson mapper the sample json string obtained was

```
{"field1":["123"],"notAtAll":["123"]}
```

This behaviour was weird and I did not get a direct explanation for this in docs, but that once a getter is made, the property is available for both serialization and deserialization. This created a property using the function name in the resultant json response.

But again on deserialization of this string to pojo, the notAtAll list got appended to field1 list, i.e. in the resultant java object, field1 had size of two with values ["123","123"] which just seems wrong. Fixed this behaviour using jsonIgnore on the getter but can someone please help explain this behaviour exactly and whether this is intended?

Answer (score 0):

A Getter Makes a Non-Public Field Serializable and Deserializable. So, no doubt that it added `notAtAll` field in json for `getNotAtAll` method. When you de-serialize the same string it has the values from both the getters but both of them return the same field i.e. `field1`. And consequently the values are added to your list. You've rightly used `@JsonIgnore` to ignore this getter.